# How do you customize the login for an ABP Blazor Server app?

Tags: authentication, server, blazor

I would be grateful if someone could direct me to a working example of how to customize the login screen for an abp blazor server app.

I found this sample, but it seems to be only for blazor webassembly.  I was not able to get it to work.
https://github.com/bartvanhoey/AbpBlazorCustomizeLoginPage

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to customize the page, not the process then you can "scaffold" the pages you want to customize.

Right click on your project, choose New -> Add Scaffolded Item, and choose Identity from the menu on the left.

[image]

Choose and set the Data Context.

Search - "blazor server authentication customize login page" for some more detailed articles.